# Adding custom PHP pages in WordPress Multisite

Tags: php, wordpress, multisite

I need to add a `script.php` for one of the sites on a WordPress multisite. So I have `site1.domain.com` and need to make `script.php` available via `site1.domain.com/script.php`

Where would I upload this file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upload to the root directory of your site (often www or the like) in the same directory as wp-config.php.

If you visit your site at `site1.domain.com/script.php` you should see your custom script.

Similarly, if you wanted `site1.domain.com/subfolder/script.php` you would upload to `www/subfolder`